# Send file to NestJS GraphQL from Nextjs apollo client

Tags: next.js, file-upload, graphql, nestjs

I'm trying to send an array of Files from the Nextjs Apollo client to the Nestjs GraphQL server. But the problem is I'm getting an array of empty objects at the backend I verified this by sending the data back to the frontend without any processing like below.

```
@Mutation(() => TaskResponseToUser)
  createTask(@Args('createTaskDto') createTaskDto: CreateTaskDto) {
    console.log('se');
    return this.taskService.create(createTaskDto);
  }

async create(createTaskDto: CreateTaskDto): Promise<TaskResponseToUser> {
    console.log(createTaskDto.attachments);
    // Here also I'm getting an array of empty objects like
    // [{},{}]
    return {
      message: 'Task created.',
      status: true,
      data: createTaskDto,
    };
  }
```

so as you can see from the above code I'm just sending back whatever data I get from the front end.
Below are the types I have used for your reference

```
@InputType()
export class CreateTaskDto {
  @Field(() => String)
  name: string;
  @Field()
  priority: string;
  @Field(() => [String], { nullable: true })
  label?: [string];
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  owner?: string;
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  assignee?: string;
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  dueDate?: string;
  @Field(() => [GraphQLUpload], { nullable: true })
  attachments?: [Upload];
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  description?: string;
}

@ObjectType()
export class CreateTask {
  @Field(() => String)
  name: string;

  @Field()
  priority: string;

  @Field(() => [String], { nullable: true })
  label?: [string];

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  owner?: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  assignee?: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  dueDate?: string;

  @Field(() => AnyType, { nullable: true })
  attachments?: any;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  description?: string;
}

@ObjectType()
export class TaskResponseToUser {
  @Field(() => String)
  message: string;

  @Field()
  status: boolean;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  data?: CreateTask;
}

const AnyType = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'Any',
  description: 'Represents any type in GraphQL',
  serialize: (value: any) => value,
  parseValue: (value: any) => value,
});
```

Here the **AnyType**, I found this from the stack over-flow answer to set a field as any in Nestjs GraphQL.

Now I will provide the code from front end

```
function saveTask() {
    const createTaskDto = {
      name: title,
      priority,
      label: labels,
      owner,
      assignee,
      dueDate,
      attachments: filesSelected,
      description
    };
    console.log(createTaskDto);
    if (title) {
      console.log('loading start');
      createTask({ variables: { createTaskDto } })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          console.log('loading end');
        });
    }
  }
```

Here filesSelected is an array of selected files.
And in the first console ***console.log(createTaskDto);*** I'm able to see the files selected like below

[image]

but I'm getting an error like the one below when I'm making a mutation call

[image]

But if I make the attachments field as type ***any*** like below

```
@InputType()
export class CreateTaskDto {
  @Field(() => String)
  name: string;
  @Field()
  priority: string;
  @Field(() => [String], { nullable: true })
  label?: [string];
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  owner?: string;
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  assignee?: string;
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  dueDate?: string;
  @Field(() => AnyType, { nullable: true })
  attachments?: any;
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  description?: string;
}
```

I won't get the error like the above but I will get an empty array of objects which clearly indicates that the server is not receiving the files that I'm sending from the client/frontend

[image]

I tried exploring some of the already existing solutions in Stack Overflow and YouTube but none of it is working in my case.
Your support will be appreciated .
I can provide any additional details you want.